# notifyicon in visual studio 2015 missing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and I'm trying to send it to notification tray following the instructions in this page http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3336751/C-Tip-Placing-Your-C-Application-in-the-System-Tray.htm

But I cannot find the NotifyIcon control in Toolbox. Is there a new control for doing this task?

Comment: It is a Winforms control, it will not appear in the toolbox for a WPF app.  Google "wpf notifyicon" for basic hits.

Answer (score 0):

NotifyIcon is not implemented in WPF as it is in Forms, but you can still use the Windows Form NofityIcon, it resides in the System.Windows.Forms namspace.

Take a look at these tutorials, they might cover your needs:

Simple solution, directly using NotifyIcon: http://www.abhisheksur.com/2012/08/notifyicon-with-wpf-applications.html

More advanced solution, new library based on NotifyIcon with more features: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon

More info about NotifyIcon can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx